# Date picker dialog for credit card expiry date in android

Tags: android

How to display *date picker dialog* in `mm/yyyy` format which does not allow the previous years and months. i.e, It shows starting from the current date on words in `android`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create like this:

```
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), null,
        calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int year = getContext().getResources()
                .getIdentifier("android:id/day", null, null);
        if(year != 0){
            View yearPicker = findViewById(year);
            if(yearPicker != null){
                yearPicker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And after you can just call:

```
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: This answers is no longer valid as they dont work starting from lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog=new DatePickerDialog(this, listener, year, month, day);
            DatePicker datepicker=datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
            //datep.removeViewAt(0);
            LinearLayout v1=(LinearLayout)datepicker.getChildAt(0);
            LinearLayout v2=(LinearLayout)v1.getChildAt(0);
            View v3=v2.getChildAt(1);
            v3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+v3.getClass().getName()+"\ncount "+v2.getChildCount(), 1).show();
            datePickerDialog.show();
```

use this code

Comment: This answers is no longer valid as they dont work starting from lollipop.